# Searching a string that may contain Null

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I have an array of triplets that can be approximated by the following code:

```
data = Table[{RandomInteger[5], RandomInteger[10], RandomChoice[{"ABC", "BCD", "DEF"}]}, {10}]
```

The first two elements of the triplet are data and the third element is a set of single-character flags.  Let's say that the flag "D" means "don't use" so I want to delete any cases containing a "D" flag.  Easy enough:

```
DeleteCases[data, x_ /; StringCases[x[[3]], "D"] == {"D"}]
```

The problem comes in for a case where a triplet contains no flags.  In this case, the third element is `Null`:

```
data = Table[{RandomInteger[5], RandomInteger[10], RandomChoice[{"ABC", "BCD", "DEF", Null}]}, {10}]
DeleteCases[data, x_ /; StringCases[x[[3]], "D"] == {"D"}]
```

The `StringCases` function throws an error whenever it attempts to compare `Null` to "D".  I would like to avoid this error message without using something like `Quiet` just in case there are other errors that shouldn't be hidden.

So the question is: how does one formulate a substring search that returns `False` instead of throwing an error if the variable passed does not have a `Head` of `String`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a pattern which specifically requires a string in the last position of the triplet:

```
DeleteCases[data, {__, s_String} /; StringCases[s, "D"] == {"D"}]
```

**Also**

As Silvia has quite rightly pointed out, it is better to use `StringMatchQ` to check for the "D". Not only is it likely to be faster, it will work with strings containing more than one "D".

```
DeleteCases[data, {__, s_String} /; StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ "D" ~~ ___]
DeleteCases[data, {__, s_String} /; StringMatchQ[s, "*D*"]
```

Comment: +1 You beat me! I'll delete mine.. btw I think `{__,s_String}/;StringMatchQ[s, ___ ~~ "D" ~~ ___]` would be faster.

Comment: @Silvia thanks for the alternative suggestion.  My database is far too small at the moment to worry about speed, but one never knows how these things grow.

Comment: @bobthechemist In fact I just tested it, and there isn't a big difference in time between your version and mine.